# Se devolverá el justificante del trámite efectuado

Tags: significado

¿Significa "volver algo a su estado anterior" el verbo "devolver" en "se devolverá el justificante del trámite efectuado y, de este modo, el certificado electrónico centralizado del sistema Cl@ve habrá quedado revocado a petición del propio usuario" en este [enlace](https://sede.agenciatributaria.gob.es/Sede/ayuda/consultas-informaticas/firma-digital-sistema-clave-pin-tecnica/modificar-datos-renunciar-servicio-clave/revocar-certificado-clave-firma.html)? ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, no significa "*volver algo a su estado anterior*". En este caso significa que si tu cambias o modificas alguno de tus datos, por ejemplo, por que ahora vives en un lugar distinto, has cambiado de calle, de ciudad o has renovado tu DNI, etc... La administración te mandará (te devolverá) un justificante a tu correo electrónico para que tu tengas constancia y seas conocedor de que esos cambios han sido realizados por ti o por alguien que tu tengas autorizado. Se intenta evitar de que alguien no autorizado, pueda cambiar tus datos sin conocimiento por tu parte.

**El texto viene a decir**;

"se **mandará a su correo electrónico** un justificante del trámite **realizado** (*teóricamente tu o persona autorizada*) y de este modo, el certificado electrónico centralizado del sistema Cl@ve habrá quedado **modificado** a petición del usuario".

Comment: ¡Hola, Diego, muchas gracias por su explicación! Y perdone por no haber podido responderle antes. Cosas pasan en la vida ...